# awk to evaluate and count comparisons with sum

Tags: loops, awk, count

I'm trying to figure out the right way to pull this off with awk (not very familiar with awk) but I can't seem to get it.

Basically I have a text file with two columns. I want to sum up the second column and then divide each entry of the second column by the sum and increment a counter if the result is less than 0.25. In order to do this it seems like I have to loop through twice, once to get the sum and once to evaluate each entry with the sum. How can I pull this off with a one-liner?

```
Example Input:
0 5
1 5
2 10
3 5

Example Output:
3 (the sum is 25 and three of the entries result in a value less than 0.25 when divided by 25)
```

I got stuck trying to do this in bash and realizing I need to use awk to deal with decimals. I can loop through and get the sum and loop through and do a conditional check on each entry but I don't understand how to do both simultaneously.

Comment: Please provide a sample input and desired output, as well as where you got stuck at.

Comment: You can save the contents of the column in an array, and then loop over it in the `END` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Untested:

```
awk '
    { sum+=$2 ; row[NR]=$2 }
    END{ for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) if (row[i]/sum < 0.25) {counter+=1}; print counter }
' file
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly thanks. Will accept soon as it is available.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
$ awk '{sum+=$2;a[NR]=$2}END{for (i in a) if (a[i]/sum<0.25) count++;print count}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `sum+=$2` get the summary on column 2 and save to `sum`
- `a[NR]=$2` record column 2 into array `a` (NR, the line number, as index)
- `i in a` get index from array `a` one by one
- `if (a[i]/sum<0.25) count++` do the calculate and increase count with the condition (<0.25)